# D3 link circle by node's names

Tags: javascript, d3.js

just getting started with D3. I am currently doing the network trading project which requires me to join nodes with other nodes depends the json file.

My json file looks like this.

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {  
           "id": "site01",
           "x": 317.5,
           "y": 282.5
        },
        {
          "id": "site02",
          "x": 112,
          "y": 47
       },
       {
          "id": "site03",
          "x": 69.5,
          "y": 287
       },
   ]
   "links": [
       {  
          "node01": "site01", 
          "node02": "site02", 
          "amount": 170
       },
       {  
          "node01": "site01", 
          "node02": "site03", 
          "amount": 100
       },
       {  
          "node01": "site02", 
          "node02": "site03", 
          "amount": 70
       },
   ]
}
```

What I am able to do write now is to plot the position of all the sites in nodes.

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var w = 1200;
      var h = 800;
      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",w).attr("height", h);
      var lines = svg.attr("class", "line")
      d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
        console.log(data);
        var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
          .data(data.nodes)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x;})
          .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y;})
          .attr("r", 20)
          .append("title") // For hover effect
          .text(function(d) { return "The site is " + d.id; });
        var lines = svg.selectAll("foo")
          .data(data.links)
          .enter()
          .append("line")
          .attr("x1", function(d) {
              return circles.filter(function(e) {
                  return e.id === d.node01
              }).attr("cx")
          })
          .attr("x2", function(d) {
              return circles.filter(function(e) {
                  return e.id === d.node02
              }).attr("cx")
          })
          .attr("y1", function(d) {
              return circles.filter(function(e) {
                  return e.id === d.node01
              }).attr("cy")
          })
          .attr("y2", function(d) {
              return circles.filter(function(e) {
                  return e.id === d.node02
              }).attr("cy")
          })
          .attr("stroke", "gray");
        circles.raise();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My question is how can I possibly draw a line between 2 sites as describe in "links" in my json file. Also, how can I change the radius of the circle based on the amount describe in "links". For example, if site01 and site02 has a link, therefore the radius of those 2 nodes would be the same.

Edit - change to current version

Thank you,

Comment: Do you need to use D3 v3 for this? It would be way easier with v4...

Comment: I do not know the different, but I think i can use v4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I first read your question's title I thought *"ok, OP wants a force directed chart"*, and that's why I asked about D3 v4.x [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913436/d3-link-circle-by-nodes-names#comment74860854_43913436)...

However, it seems to me that you don't want a force directed: you already have the circles' positions. You just want to link them.

That being the case, you can filter the circles' selection to get the lines' `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2`:

```
var lines = svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(data.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return circles.filter(function(e) {
            return e.id === d.node01
        }).attr("cx")
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return circles.filter(function(e) {
            return e.id === d.node02
        }).attr("cx")
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return circles.filter(function(e) {
            return e.id === d.node01
        }).attr("cy")
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return circles.filter(function(e) {
            return e.id === d.node02
        }).attr("cy")
    })
    .attr("stroke", "gray");
```

Here is the demo using your code and that selection for the lines:

```js
var data = {
  "nodes": [{
    "id": "site01",
    "x": 317.5,
    "y": 282.5
  }, {
    "id": "site02",
    "x": 112,
    "y": 47
  }, {
    "id": "site03",
    "x": 69.5,
    "y": 287
  }],
  "links": [{
    "node01": "site01",
    "node02": "site02",
    "amount": 170
  }, {
    "node01": "site01",
    "node02": "site03",
    "amount": 100
  }, {
    "node01": "site02",
    "node02": "site03",
    "amount": 70
  }]
};

var w = 400;
var h = 320;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);
var lines = svg.attr("class", "line")

var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("r", 20);

circles.append("title")
  .text(function(d) {
    return "The site is " + d.id;
  });

var lines = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data.links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", function(d) {
    return circles.filter(function(e) {
      return e.id === d.node01
    }).attr("cx")
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return circles.filter(function(e) {
      return e.id === d.node02
    }).attr("cx")
  })
  .attr("y1", function(d) {
    return circles.filter(function(e) {
      return e.id === d.node01
    }).attr("cy")
  })
  .attr("y2", function(d) {
    return circles.filter(function(e) {
      return e.id === d.node02
    }).attr("cy")
  })
  .attr("stroke", "gray");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

And here the same code, but with the lines *behind* the circles:

```js
var data = {
  "nodes": [{
    "id": "site01",
    "x": 317.5,
    "y": 282.5
  }, {
    "id": "site02",
    "x": 112,
    "y": 47
  }, {
    "id": "site03",
    "x": 69.5,
    "y": 287
  }],
  "links": [{
    "node01": "site01",
    "node02": "site02",
    "amount": 170
  }, {
    "node01": "site01",
    "node02": "site03",
    "amount": 100
  }, {
    "node01": "site02",
    "node02": "site03",
    "amount": 70
  }]
};

var w = 400;
var h = 320;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);
var lines = svg.attr("class", "line")

var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("r", 20);

circles.append("title")
  .text(function(d) {
    return "The site is " + d.id;
  });

var lines = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data.links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", function(d) {
    return circles.filter(function(e) {
      return e.id === d.node01
    }).attr("cx")
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return circles.filter(function(e) {
      return e.id === d.node02
    }).attr("cx")
  })
  .attr("y1", function(d) {
    return circles.filter(function(e) {
      return e.id === d.node01
    }).attr("cy")
  })
  .attr("y2", function(d) {
    return circles.filter(function(e) {
      return e.id === d.node02
    }).attr("cy")
  })
  .attr("stroke", "gray");
  
circles.raise();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried to add var lines under var circles but it seems that the line wasn't displayed. It does generate lines equals to the number of links. I have edit my current code in my question, if you don't mind have a look what went wrong on my implementation. Thank you